suspend crontab until next system boot
How would I suspend all use of crontab until the system is rebooted?  The system runs ubuntu 24.04. I say all use because several IDs on the system have crontabs.

Stop its service
sudo systemctl stop cron.service

(It would make more sense to start cron BEFORE reboot if you do it after the "@reboot" options in your crontabs will not activate
manual restart:
sudo systemctl start cron.service

)

Excellent point that a reboot will not restart a service which has been intentially stopped.  I forgot that point.

@thing1 it will. Why do you think that? With systemd you need to disable a service to prevent it from starting on reboot

@thing1 it will be it is far more logical to start BEFORE reboot and not after a reboot
